# Multiplying permutation matrix by itself to get identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutations, permutation-matrices

What is rigorous proof that any permutation matrix $P$ raised to some power $k$ equals identity matrix i.e. $P^k= I_n$?

Is there any way to find the smallest $k$ other than looking at the matrix, finding all its cycles and then calculating least common multiple?

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group of permutation matrices of size $n$ is isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_n$. Any permutation $\sigma$ has finite order, hence any permutation matrix also has finite order.

*Added: decomposition of a permutation as  a product of disjoint cycles* (example)

Let's take the permutation of $S_8$:
$$\sigma=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\5&4&6&3&1&7&8&2\end{pmatrix}$$
We also can represent this permutation in the following way: starting with $1$, we compute its image by $\sigma$, then the image of $\sigma(1)$, and so on, until we get back to $1$. When this is done, we have obtained a cycle. If there remains elements in $\{1,2,\dots,8\}$, we do the same starting from the smallest element.
Here we obtain:
$$\sigma=(1\,5)(2\,4\,3\,6\,7\,8)$$
Thus $\sigma$ is the product of a $2$-cycle (a ‘`transposition`’) and a $6$-cycle.

Now a cycle of length $\ell$ has order $\ell$: indeed
\begin{align*}
\sigma^2&=(2\,3\,7)(4\,6\,8)& \sigma^3&=(2\,6)(3\,8)(4\,7)\\
\sigma^4&=(2\,7)(3)(4\,8)(6)& \sigma^5&=(2\,8\,7\,6\,3\,4) \\
\sigma^6&=\operatorname{id}
\end{align*}
Also, the order of the product of disjoint cycles is the l.c.m. of the orders (lengths) of the cycles.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't thought of this. Do you know anything about finding the smallest $k$?

Comment: It should be the same as the decomposition of permutations as products of disjoint cycles.

Comment: Could you give some more insight? I get what a matrix decomposition is but what exactly do you mean by _decomposition of permutations_? Thanks;)

Comment: I meant decompositions of permutations of $S_n$. Did you have a class on permutation groups?

Comment: I have not, yet:/

Comment: This *should* be done in high school… OK, I'll add an example.

Comment: @user2781994 Alternatively you can find the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $P$ and the smallest $k$ such that $\lambda_i^k=1$.

Comment: I'm sorry to waste your time;) This is what I meant by "looking at the matrix." Sure I know how to do this. The term "permutation groups" scared me a bit and wiki page didn't help:D I'm not native speaker so it's sometimes harder to make those connections since it's named differently. Thank you and sorry again;)